# How to convert 1D array of pixels to image in python?

Tags: python, image, detection, emotion

This is with respect to the [FER2013 dataset](https://www.kaggle.com/c/challenges-in-representation-learning-facial-expression-recognition-challenge/data). The data consists of 48x48 pixel grayscale images of faces. The CSV file contains three columns as (emotion, pixels, Usage), where Usage has any of three value - training, PrivateTest and PublicTest. I want to read the array of pixels, convert them into an image and save them in the respective folder named as per their Usage type.

I need python code that can do the above.
Following is my code

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image

df=pd.read_csv("fer2013.csv")
for rows in df:
  
   arr=np.array(df['pixels'])
   print(arr)
   print(arr.shape)
   img = Image.fromarray(arr.reshape(48,48), 'L')
   img.save("dataset/df['Usage']/img.jpg", "JPEG")
```

The above code shows error:

> cannot reshape array of size 35887 into shape (48,48).

Comment: I am also confused about how an array of pixels (each image is of 48*48 pixel)  have the shape (35887, ).

Comment: How do those pixels create that size image?  That's not even a perfect square.  You should have a 2304 length array

Comment: i think you meant to write `arr = np.array(rows['pixels'])` or something similar

Comment: @chrisz Thanks , the code you provided worked. But for converting array of pixel to image through fromarray is still not working. Its showing error as : 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'mask'

Comment: @MohammadAthar Yes that was one of the mistakes I was doing. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In case there are any doubts (because I have been working with the FER dataset):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image

df = pd.read_csv('fer2013.csv')
for image_pixels in df.iloc[1:,1]: #column 2 has the pixels. Row 1 is column name.
    image_string = image_pixels.split(' ') #pixels are separated by spaces.
    image_data = np.asarray(image_string, dtype=np.uint8).reshape(48,48)
    img = Image.fromarray(image_data) #final image
```